# Think or regard in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Can I use either "think" or "regard" in my sentence?

"I do think/regard that love is for dreamers."

Comment: No. "I regard love as being..."

Comment: Please give us more to go on in your question. Are you asking about the meaning of the two words or the grammaticality? What sources have you consulted so far? What did you find? In what way was it not helpful enough?